# How do I test associated models with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

In my app I have following models:

```
class UserApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :builds, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end


class Build < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_application
end
```

And User model is generated by *Devise*.

My question is: is I want to test, say, model validations, should I do it like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserApplication do

  it "is invalid without name" do
    user_application = UserApplication.new(name: nil)
    expect(user_application).to have(1).errors_on(:name)
  end
end
```

Or should I create *UserApplication* through *User*? In general, should I bear in mind associations when testing my models, if test example is not connected to relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems prudent to have test code parallel app code as closely as possible. That is, if UserApplication will be created via User in the controller, it ought to be done the same way in the test. Furthermore, your UserApplication validations will probably test the association sooner or later anyway, so the test subject should be created in such a way as to be valid. With that in mind, you can set up your tests as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserApplication do
  let(:user) { User.create(user_params) }
  before { @user_application = user.user_applications.build(name: 'name') }

  subject { @user_application }

  describe 'validations' do
    context 'when name is missing' do
      before { @user_application.name = '' }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    context 'when user_id is missing' do
      before { @user_application.user_id = nil }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    # other validations
  end
end
```

Comment: And this obviously is valid for "chain" of relations? I.e. User has many UserApplications, and UserApplication has many Builds. So to test Build model, I create User and than UserApplication?

Comment: Indeed. This ensures that all test models pass their respective validations and prevents a situation where e.g. Build model's tests fail because upstream UserApplication was not created properly, failed its validations and was not saved to the database.

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov: My point is that tests should parallel the app's logic. If UserApplications are initially being created via Users in controllers, I'd do the same in the tests, and if a logic change occurs, then refactor the tests first and the controllers second for proper TDD. If, on the other hand, a UserApplication can exist without being bound to a User, then there is no need to create it via a User object in the tests.

Comment: I think this is a bad solution to rely on relations, because if you will change your logic, for example remove one relation all your tests will go down(those tests are not isolated and rely on another model existence which is bad practice), even though your validation/attribute/method/etc tests for this model should pass, in my case only the should have_many/belong_to test will become red which is correct.

Comment: @Nikita Avvakumov this is model specs and you are talking about controller's specs. If in controller you are creating a `user_application` instance through `user` it would be correct to write a tests with same way of object creation, but not in this case

Answer (score 1):

You should test validations/associations/fields existence/etc in corresponding specs. I don't see your `UserApplication` validations, but if I correctly understand you, your specs for this model should look like this(I am using [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) and [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gems for testing):

```ruby
require 'spec_helper'

describe UserApplication do
  let!(:user_application) { create(:user_application) }

  it { should have_many(:builds).dependent(:destroy) }
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:name) }
end
```

I am always creating only the instance of the model I want to test. It is important to test that associations exist and correct, but you don't need to create testing model instance through association.

Comment: What I mean is that when I create UserApplication, should it be like user_application = UserApplication.new(...) or should I create user first and then write user_application = @user.user_applications.new(...)?
Is that important in my case?

Comment: In my opinion your first guess(`UserApplication.new(...)`) is correct. Because you can test that `user_applications` association exists in `user_spec`.